# Getting error while building app in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/appcompat/appcompat/1.2.0/appcompat-1.2.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/appcompat/appcompat/1.2.0/appcompat-1.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project:app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: There's some problem with your gradle i think. It might be due to version incompatibility

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `com.android.appcompat:appcompat` with `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` in your `build.gradle` file